# Treat tap like mouse over only, not like click

Tags: jquery, user-interface, hover, click, touch

I have a user interface, which is best used with a mouse. But it's easily possible to use it on a touchscreen, as well.
[image]
There's a big `table` with many rows and columns.

You hover, and the TD you're on gets highlighted.
This allows you to see if you got the correct TD.
You click on the highlighted TD and now a confirming action happens.

Here's what I envision happening on mobile:

You tap, and the TD you're on gets highlighted.
This allows you to see if you got the correct TD.
You tap again on the highlighted TD and now a confirming action happens.

So this is what I had before:

```
$(document).on('mousover','td.cell',function(){
    cell.highlight();
});
$(document).on('click','td.cell',function(){
    cell.confirm();
});
$(document).on('mouseleave','td.cell',function(){
    cell.clearHighlight();
});
```

What I thought would be an easy fix

```
$(document).on('click','td.cell',function(){
    if(cell.isHighlighted)
        cell.confirm();
    else
        cell.highlight();
});
```

keep everything else the same.

but what happens, on mobile I will trigger BOTH the mouseover AND the click in a single tap. Therefore it will highlight and then right away confirm.

How can I make sure they won't happen at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

How about instead of onclick, you use a onfocus?

1. This a pure css method which I prefer and css tends to be much more compatible across all devices.
2. You would be using a styling class that commonly exists.
3. Same class styling: I like having same styling when possible.
4. onFocus is meant to be highlighted onFocus (click) and also has hover effects if you want to still use that for desktop users.
   5.Desktop users have to stay put hovering on onHover to keep highlight whereas mobile users stay focused on.) Which makes for the better UX?

To me, it is less code, light weight, css with existing current classes, and more compatible.

At least that is my thoughts.
Cheers :)

Comment: I like the idea, but there's no real difference if I use `.on('click'` or `.on('focus click'`. On mobile devices, with one tap I'm still triggering both, the mouseover AND the click (or focus click). Let me know if I'm misunderstanding

Comment: I guess that would be a great solution - unfortunately my implementation is a bit more complicated. I'm working within an existing ecommerce system, so I'm adapting within their stylesheets and tables, etc. Also I'm highlighting more than just one cell at a time, involving complicated rules. So I think I'm forced to use Javascript. Good answer anyways!! :-)

Comment: @olli So if I may ask, what is the method being used as the secondary click from a hover state? How and what is being called? Cheers!

Comment: It's essentially a canlendar. And clicking will bring up a dialog, summarizing your booking, offering a few extra options, and then you can say "confirm appointment"

Answer (score 1):

These are 2 pretty completely different answers so I added a second method.

> but what happens, on mobile I will trigger BOTH the mouseover AND the
>   click in a single tap. Therefore it will highlight and then right away
>   confirm.
>
> How can I make sure they won't happen at the same time?

You can look for mobile devices and omit `.hover` for them.

```
if(!!('ontouchstart' in window)){
//touch device events go here
}
else{
//mouse device events go here
}
```